# Oracle Apex Onscreen Keyboard

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, on-screen-keyboard, oracle18c

I want to developed restaurant management system on Oracle Apex front-end like below screenshots taken from desktop applications which was developed on .net. I just want to show my developed numeric keyboard on screen and to prevent device keyboard to be opened throughout application. I'm using oracle apex 18c. You will get my point clearly after looking into below screenshot.

[image: Login Screen with onscreen keyboard]
[image: Transaction form with onscreen keyboard]

Comment: Personally to approach this I'd just use ordinary buttons on the page instead of trying to fiddle around with the keyboard. Each button could execute some simple javascript to append a value to an existing item on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the layout manually. In this case default components are not going to help you a lot, If I were you, I will try to create my own html and css and implemented into static region.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create this layout in APEX, There is more than one approach to develop this layout.

**One of the easiest approach is:**

- Create a static region with text fields and buttons which executes
  dynamic actions on click.
- If you want to display the clicked Button text, store the value in an
  APEX Item and return it so that it will be displayed in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Easy pease, just remember that APEX apps are responsive and things may look different in certain screens.

You can create Static Regions with button or page items and have them occupy a spefici number of columns (Column Span property). that should work for your grids.

For the inputs, instead of the template being "Floating" or "Optional Above", just change it to "Optional", which will make the labels stay on the left side. Btw, when you change it to optional it will enable a "Label Column Span" which you can use to define the size of the label.

Comment: hi, it's been a while. did it work?